# CSV: concatenate more line data

Tags: command-line, text-processing, csv

I have this `file1.csv`:

```
A,dog cat horse cow
B,goat deer fish
A,deer goat 
C,dog cat 
C,goat
```

I need to merge join the similar lines (es. A and C):

```
A,dog cat horse cow deer goat 
B,goat deer fish
C,dog cat goat
```

Answer (score 5):

With `awk`:

```
$ awk -F, '{a[$1] = a[$1]=="" ? $2 : a[$1] OFS $2} END {for (i in a) printf("%s,%s\n", i, a[i])}' file.csv
A,dog cat horse cow deer goat
B,goat deer fish
C,dog cat  goat
```

With GNU `datamash` + `sed`:

```
$ datamash -st, groupby 1 collapse 2 < file.csv | sed 's/,/ /2g'
A,dog cat horse cow deer goat
B,goat deer fish
C,dog cat  goat
```

Note that the output order is not guaranteed in the awk version: if you have GNU awk >= 4.0  you can control that using the `PROCINFO` structure.

Answer (score 1):

You can also first `sort` and then process with `awk`:

```
$ <file1.csv sort -sk1,1.1|awk -F, '{printf(a==$1)?" "$2:(NR<2)?$0:"\n"$0;a=$1}END{print""}'
A,dog cat horse cow deer goat
B,goat deer fish
C,dog cat goat
```